# Proof of the Second Isomorphism Theorem for modules

Tags: proof-verification, modules

Here's my attempt to prove the Second Isomorphism Theorem for modules. Could you please verify if everything is correct and give suggestions? **Edit:** The proof I present follows the suggestions given.

> Let $M$ be a R-module and let $S$ and $T$ be R-submodules
>   of $M$. Then:
>
> i) $S+T\leq M$ ($S+T$ is a R-submodule of $M$)
>
> ii) $S\cap T\leq M$
>
> iii) $S/(S\cap T)\simeq (S+T)/T$

**Proof:**
Clearly $S+T$ and $S\cap T$ are subsets of $M$. Now I will use
the fact that $N$ is an R-submodule of $M$ if $N$ is an additive
subgroup of $M$ and $rn\in N$ for every $r\in R$ and $n\in N$.

Since $0_{S}+0_{T}=0_{M}+0_{M}=0_{M}\in M$, $S+T\neq\emptyset$.
Given $s_{1}+t_{1},\,\,s_{2}+t_{2}\in S+T$, $s_{1}+t_{1}-(s_{2}+t_{2})=s_{1}-s_{2}+t_{1}-t_{2}$
and the last equality holds because $M$ is an R-module, in particular
it is an additive abelian group. $s_{1}-s_{2}\in S$ because $S$
is an R-module, so in particular it is an abelian additive group.
The same argument ensures that $t_{1}-t_{2}\in T$ so $s_{1}+t_{1}-(s_{2}+t_{2})\in S+T$
which proves that $S+T$ is an additive subgroup of $M$.

Also, for every $r\in R$, $r(s+t)=rs+rt$ and each of these elements
belong to $S$ and $T$, respectively, since they both are R-modules.
This completes the proof of i).

A similar argument would prove ii). However, I will skip it for now
and justify this later.

To prove iii), let $\phi$ be the mapping $S\rightarrow(S+T)/T$ such
that $\phi(s)=s+T$. $\phi$ is a homomorphism because $\phi(s_{1}+s_{2})=(s_{1}+s_{2})+T=s_{1}+T+s_{2}+T=\phi(s_{1})+\phi(s_{2})$
and $\phi(rs)=rs+T=r(s+T)=r\phi(s)$. Notice that $\phi$ is surjective.
Computing the kernel of $\phi$ gives $\left\{ s\in S\,:\,\phi(s)=0\right\} =\left\{ s\in S\,:\,s\in T\right\} =S\cap T$.
The kernel of $\phi$ is an R-submodule of $S$, which proves ii).

By the first isomorphism theorem for modules, $S/(S\cap T)\simeq(S+T)/T$.

Comment: The notation $(s_2+t_2)^{-1}$ for the additive inverse is confusing and probably shouldn't be used.  In the $\ker \phi$ the set should be $\{s\in S : s \in T\}$

Comment: @sharding4 Please check the edits I've done.

Comment: That's better.  I'm not sure I understand the line $e_{S}+e_{T}=e_{M}+e_{M}=e_{M}\in M$  What's going on there?  What's $e_{S}, e_{T}, e_{M}$?

Comment: That the identity element of the additive abelian group. Maybe I should use the 0 notation...  $0_{S}+0_{T}=0_{M}+0_{M}=0_{M}\in M$.

Comment: Zero would be better.  $e$ typically represents an idempotent (which zero is but not every idempotent is zero, for instance 1).

Comment: Now I understand why in group theory we usually use $e$. Also, I added a sentence after computing the kernel of the mapping, which proves ii).